get JSON object having specific key including root JSON object
Hi I'm struggling to find the JSONPATH expression to get all the JSON object having a specific key including the root JSON object.
For example:
{
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": 2,
    "key3": {
        "key1": 4,
        "key4": 5,
        "key5": {
            "key1": true
        }
    }
}

should return
[
    {
        "key1": 1,
        "key2": 2,
        "key3": {
            "key1": 4,
            "key4": 5,
            "key5": {
                "key1": true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": 4,
        "key4": 5,
        "key5": {
            "key1": true
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": true
    }
]

I tried multiple combination with the closest one being $..*[?(@.key1)] but it failed to return the root JSON object.
Thank you for helping me.

Where is the json coming from. Is it an api? What you are looking for is a JSON that returns a list of objects like the first example.
Is the APi returning a single Json or a List Json?

jq '[.,.]' input.json

the JSON value is coming from an API and it's a JSON object yes not a JSON array

Do you consider a multiple-step approach? (step 1) search output paths matching $..key1 and you obtain [   "$['key1']",   "$['key3']['key1']",   "$['key3']['key5']['key1']" ], (step 2) strip ["key1"] from all these output paths obtaining [   "$",   "$['key3']",   "$['key3']['key5']" ], (step 3) use each of these output paths to match an object, so $, $['key3'] and $['key3']['key5'] which results are the three objects you are looking for and can be (step 4) simply concatenated

"......it's a JSON object yes not a JSON array"  But an array is an object, so please share the code you have to make it clear what your are doing.

""......it's a JSON object yes not a JSON array" But an array is an object" not per the JSON specification https://www.json.org/json-en.html array and object are two different JSON values

I actually raised this while we were finalizing the spec (RFC 9535).
https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base/issues/390
Essentially, recursive descent (the ..) only looks at descendants, not the root.
There's some further discussion there, and you're welcome to add your 2¢.  If anything, it could be as part of a JSON Path v2 (if that happens).

wow thank you so much @gregsdennis I won't waste more time anymore on the subject.
